# What are [employment] benefits?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

Tag [employment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) currently shows <strike>24</strike> 9 old questions, all closed and most are of low score / views. What makes it troublesome is that it seems to still attract blatantly off-topic questions (recent example - [10K link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359898/what-do-i-need-to-study-to-become-a-compiler-engineer)).

Given above, suggest to burninate this tag.

I tried to edit it out of questions that look worth keeping but I could miss some - please take a look.

---

<sup>On a historical note, this tag was [submitted for blacklisting](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7355/31260) in the course of STCI-II. Probably back then it had more questions and it seemed that we need CM team help in handling it. But as of now it appears to become small enough to be dealt with by site community.</sup>

Comment: I'd like to do more to remove bad tags, but there's something of a problem that I've run into a few times. Sometimes, all of the tags on a question are bad, but a question can't be tagless. Normally, deletion would be OK. But sometimes, these are questions that have a very large number of views and are historically locked. I want to avoid metatags (since they are incredibly evil). I'm not sure what the right solution is. It looks like some questions in this tag may fall into that category.

Comment: @ThomasOwens your comment reminded me of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/how-useful-are-it-headhunters-recruiters-when-looking-for-a-new-job), very tough nut to crack tag wise. It stands at the last place in my "tag edit queue" because I want to free my mind to focus on it after completing simpler cases (luckily we're not in a hurry here)

Comment: @gnat the proper action to take on the question you linked is to nuke the question itself.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm almost ready to give up on that [headhunters-useful question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27083/how-useful-are-it-headhunters-recruiters-when-looking-for-a-new-job) from my prior comment. Messing aroung it since weekend and just can't figure any legitimate tag for it. Least harmful idea that came to mind was to retag it to [tag:profession] - also not a very good tag but it somehow appears to be less appealing for folks dumping off-topic questions (FWIW it looks like profession became kind of a dump-tag for various historically locked questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no questions with this tag anymore. Thanks to all who participated in cleanup.