# Is the [recruiting] tag on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [recruiting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recruiting)  has been around for a while.  That tag info appears to have been copied from Wikipedia.  It has 14 questions, the 12 oldest of which are closed.  Does this tag invite off-topic content?  Does the process of searching for and hiring developers count as Software Engineering?

Should the tag be burninated (deleted/removed/marked DO NOT USE/etc.)?

Comment: FWIW this tag was listed for burnination in [STCI Phase II](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7355/31260)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions for which the recruiting tag is applicable usually ask for career advice, which is off-topic for this site. IMHO it is ok not to delete tag entirely, since historically the related kind of questions were on-topic 10 years ago.

Yes, I think it should be marked. However, I am not happy with the "DO NOT USE" phrasing - this sometimes leads to not using a specific tag, but asking an off-topic question either, with different tags.

A better phrase would be "If you think this tag applies, CONSIDER NOT TO ASK here - since the question will most probably get closed and deleted as off-topic." I will see what I can do here to edit the specific tag note.